# Convert DataBytes into UIImage

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I want to convert Databytes into UIImage..

Comment: which types of databytes... in exactly what format...

Comment: I'm getting bytes from server 00FhX like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData: NSData_yourDataBytes];
```

Answer (score 1):

use  these methods see in documentation

```
+ (UIImage *)imageWithData:(NSData *)data

 - (id)initWithData:(NSData *)data
```

Answer (score 0):

Go through this link

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/35906-convert-bytes-into-uiimage.html
you can also use `imageWithData`: